# Java Applet from Oracle example says "applet.function is not a function"

Tags: java, javascript, applet

I'm trying to run Java Applet from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingAppletMethodsFromJavaScript.html) Oracle example for invoking applet's methods from Javascript. I have not made any changes to it. When js invokes applet's function, nothing happened but the error occures in js console saying `mathApplet.getGreeting is not a function` (in Firefox). This does not works in Chrome too. This is my first time I'm dealing with Java so I could miss something important. I'm using Intellij Idea.

Comment: *"This is my first time I'm dealing with Java"*  And you've bitten off GUIs embedded in a browser, that interact with JS.  ..Happy chewing! ;)

Comment: well, it is not so scary as it sounds, is it? Also, I got a ready example. Now or a bit later I will solve that, but I will be appreciated a lot if someone will point me my mistake.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536814/java-error-in-firefox-myapplet-myfunction-is-not-a-function. Additionaly the link you shared has the source code. You could download that and check.

Comment: @verisimilitude I'm running this source code without changes, I've mentioned that. That link has another problem at first glance, with visibility of applet... but thanks, I'll look into it deeper

Comment: *"Now or a bit later I will solve that"*  LOL.  Keep chewing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually, there were two errors - first, I forgot to place .jnlp file on the right place, and second (this is pretty strange), which I got after modifying code a bit - `document.writeln("...")` before invocation of applet's function causes applet not to work.